# How to efficiently extract segments from pandas dataframe given list of start stop index

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe df

```
    A   B   C
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
3   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
... ... ... ...
410 0   0   0
411 0   0   0
412 0   0   0
413 0   0   0
414 0   0   0
```

and a list contains pairs of start and stop index index_list. I want to extract subsets (segments) from df using these indexes.

```
[[0, 41],
 [42, 57],
 [62, 70],
 [71, 78],
 [84, 90],
 [91, 98],
 [105, 113],
 [114, 352],
 [353, 407]]
```

Apart from a for loop like this:

```
for start_index, stop_index in index_list:
    segments = df.iloc[start_index:stop_index].copy()
```

are there any better/faster way to extract these segments?

Comment: "*better/faster way*" -> to do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform your list of start/stop indexes into a mapping of the dataframe row id to segment id.  You could then add a column that includes the segment number instead of extracting each into a separate dataframe.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'A':[0]*415, 'B':[0]*415, 'C':[0]*415})
segment_ids = [[0, 41],
 [42, 57],
 [62, 70],
 [71, 78],
 [84, 90],
 [91, 98],
 [105, 113],
 [114, 352],
 [353, 407]]
segments = pandas.Series(
    {
        index: number
        for number, segment in enumerate([range(*segment) for segment in segment_ids])
        for index in segment
    },
    name='segment'
)
result = df.join(segments).dropna()
```

Output:

```
     A  B  C   segment
0    0  0  0         0
1    0  0  0         0
2    0  0  0         0
3    0  0  0         0
4    0  0  0         0
..  .. .. ..       ...
402  0  0  0         8
403  0  0  0         8
404  0  0  0         8
405  0  0  0         8
406  0  0  0         8

[384 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot adding a new column is indeed more efficient than manipulating the whole dataframe. But in your code, the variable `ids` should be `segments` :p

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I have updated now.